# Selecting records in SQL table if either JOIN statement is satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of `Companies` that I'd like to filter to just the records that are referenced from two other tables, `Employees` and `Contracts`.

My initial instinct is that I might be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Companies c
JOIN Employees ON EmployerId = c.Id
JOIN Contracts ON CompanyId = c.Id
```

However, this selects the records that are referenced from both `Employees` and `Contracts` tables.

How do I rewrite this query to match records that are referenced from either table?

Comment: Sounds like you need [intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially put up a buggy version that failed, with LEFT OUTER JOINS. It could have been fixed but it's actually probably more efficient to use WHERE EXISTS e.g.,

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Companies c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT EmployerID FROM Employee WHERE EmployerID = c.ID)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT CompanyId FROM Contracts WHERE CompanyId = c.ID)
```

The reason my previous version was buggy, was that it had a join to Employees and Contracts, which meant it would return one row for every one that existed (and indeed, possibly the cross-product of results). Even with a GROUP BY or DISTINCT, it is likely SQL Server would have had to do a lot of work.

The above solution just gets one row per Company, regardless of number of employees or contracts.

Comment: This seems much more elegant than the conventional solution, which is to do a UNION on the JOINs. By the time I called DISTINCT to remove dupes, I suspect that it's much slower than what you've proposed.

Comment: Since the results of this query is being put into a temporary table, my current workaround is just adding the second JOIN into the temporary table with INSERT INTO.  This also works, but it's not all that fast and doesn't deal with duplicates.

Comment: Would this perform any better if I use "SELECT 1" instead of  "SELECT EmployerId" and "SELECT CompanyId"?

Comment: 'SELECT 1' may give you a very very minor performance boost. 'SELECT * ' may also do so. But in practice I haven't noticed a difference. Try turning `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON` and try them (in different orders) to see. Regarding best answers, sometimes it depends on data size and indexes. If you have lots of data, the above may also cause problems. You could also try `SELECT c.* FROM Companies c INNER JOIN (SELECT EmployerID as ID FROM Employees UNION SELECT CompanyID FROM Contracts) a ON c.Id = a.Id`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a `UNION` to get this done

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Companies c
JOIN Employees ON EmployerId = c.Id
UNION
SELECT c.* 
FROM Companies c
JOIN Contracts ON CompanyId = c.Id
```